# HTTP request without encoding

Tags: c#

I need to send a http request without encoding (I have to consume a stupid supplier API that breaks if you encode your urls)

so currently I have

```
    string address = "https://www.eco-bb.bt.com/bbxml33/batchstatus.asp?b_customerId=[O/M12346800]&batchid=[" + batchID + "]";
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
```

Which produces

> POST
>   https://www.eco-bb.bt.com/bbxml33/Upload.asp?b_customerId=%5BO/M12346800%5D

And I want it to produce

> POST
>   https://www.eco-bb.bt.com/bbxml33/Upload.asp?b_customerId=[O/M12346800]

I'm a little stumped. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: You need to escape those characters. Does the server not understand the escaped characters?

Comment: No, it fails validation if I escape the characters. I know its stupid.

Comment: It sounds like you're going to have to get your hands dirty and write your own non-standard HTTP by using a Socket. :(

Comment: Let your supplier know that they should pull their socks up and present a better API to the world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running .NET 4 or later you can add the following [config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee656539.aspx)

```
<configuration>
  <uri>
    <schemeSettings>
      <add name="http" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes"/>
    </schemeSettings>
  </uri>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one, you create an `Uri` object and promise the constructor that you already escaped the string (which you didn't :p)

```
string address = "https://www.eco-bb.bt.com/bbxml33/batchstatus.asp?b_customerId=[O/M12346800]&batchid=[" + batchID + "]";
Uri uri = new Uri(address, true);
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
```

Comment: Deleted my answer. `Uri uri = new Uri(address, true);` Is deprecated though :(

Comment: Didn't notice that. So it's either ignoring the obsolete warning or implementing it with a TcpSocket.

Comment: I would prefer the deprecated warning more then changing the config as proposed by blowdart. It will warn other programmers that work on the same code that something tricky happens there that is not conform to the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, being a dinosaur I remembered that in the old days you would sometimes manually encode your URL data by replacing special characters with your own specific names and then parsing them out on the Server side. If this is how your supplier built their web app then they're just going to have to tell you what special character replacements they expect e.g.

```
http://www.this.com?variable=[12]
```

might be expected as;

```
http://www.this.com?variable=lBracket12rBracket
```

As an aside a call to their service without the HTTPS results in some interesting JavaScript functions!

```
 <script> 
   function Homepage(){
<!--
// in real bits, urls get returned to our script like this:
// res://shdocvw.dll/http_404.htm#http://www.DocURL.com/bar.htm 

    //For testing use DocURL = "res://shdocvw.dll/http_404.htm#https://www.microsoft.com/bar.htm"
    DocURL=document.URL;

    //this is where the http or https will be, as found by searching for :// but skipping the res://
    protocolIndex=DocURL.indexOf("://",4);

    //this finds the ending slash for the domain server 
    serverIndex=DocURL.indexOf("/",protocolIndex + 3);

    //for the href, we need a valid URL to the domain. We search for the # symbol to find the begining 
    //of the true URL, and add 1 to skip it - this is the BeginURL value. We use serverIndex as the end marker.
    //urlresult=DocURL.substring(protocolIndex - 4,serverIndex);
    BeginURL=DocURL.indexOf("#",1) + 1;
    urlresult=DocURL.substring(BeginURL,serverIndex);

    //for display, we need to skip after http://, and go to the next slash
    displayresult=DocURL.substring(protocolIndex + 3 ,serverIndex);
    InsertElementAnchor(urlresult, displayresult);
}

function HtmlEncode(text)
{
    return text.replace(/&/g, '&amp').replace(/'/g, '&quot;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}

function TagAttrib(name, value)
{
    return ' '+name+'="'+HtmlEncode(value)+'"';
}

function PrintTag(tagName, needCloseTag, attrib, inner){
    document.write( '<' + tagName + attrib + '>' + HtmlEncode(inner) );
    if (needCloseTag) document.write( '</' + tagName +'>' );
}

function URI(href)
{
    IEVer = window.navigator.appVersion;
    IEVer = IEVer.substr( IEVer.indexOf('MSIE') + 5, 3 );

    return (IEVer.charAt(1)=='.' && IEVer >= '5.5') ?
        encodeURI(href) :
        escape(href).replace(/%3A/g, ':').replace(/%3B/g, ';');
}

function InsertElementAnchor(href, text)
{
    PrintTag('A', true, TagAttrib('HREF', URI(href)), text);
}

//-->
</script>
```